# Selecting row data from one table, then insert into another table using TableAdapter

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, tableadapter

I'm using TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard. I want to select a data from one table and insert into another as shown in the statement below.

```
SELECT a.StudentID FROM [dbo].[Student] AS a WHERE [Email] = @Email;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Registration] ([StudentID], [UniformOptionID], [Cost])
VALUES (a.StudentID, @Param1, @Param2);
```

When I call out the function on my application, The error message prompts:

`Error message: The multi-part identifier "a.StudentID" could not be bound`

Why is this not possible?

Comment: Check this article on how to use INSERT with SELECT : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[registration] 
        ([studentid], 
         [uniformoptionid], 
         [cost]) 
SELECT a.studentid, 
   @Param1, 
   @Param2 
FROM   [dbo].[student] AS a 
WHERE  [email] = @Email;
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use `a.StudentID` in your Insert statement. you can declare a variable then use it. Like this

```
Declare @studentID int

SELECT @studentID=a.StudentID FROM [dbo].[Student] AS a WHERE [Email] = @Email;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Registration] ([StudentID], [UniformOptionID], [Cost])
VALUES (@studentID, @Param1, @Param2);
```

Comment: My TableAdapter function has no option to enter the parameters for my Email.

Comment: please share TableAdapter function code. so that i can understand better.

Comment: `RegistrationTableAdapter1.RegisterCourse(UniformOptionID as String, Cost as String, Email as String)`

`Cost as String` should be decimal. I'm not sure why, but doesn't make any errors.

Comment: You have accepted the answer. So your problem is solved, I guess :)

Comment: Thanks for contributing though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Registration] ([StudentID], [UniformOptionID], [Cost])
SELECT a.StudentID, @Param1, @Param2 FROM [dbo].[Student] AS a WHERE [Email] = @Email;
```

i.e, you can use the `select` statement to insert the values in your table. The `@Param1, @Param2` can be provided directly in the `select` statement.

Comment: Great answer. Works too.